# Retrieving id of DIV fails

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to load up a DIV by default (dpara) and then allow the user to switch through DIVs depending on the button they press.

On page load - dpara is visible but dtab and ddl are not.

If the user picks dtab for example, dpara is hidden, dtab becomes visible and ddl remains hidden.

But this doesn't seem to be working since I've updated my code from this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        function arrange(div_id) {
            // First make all the divs hidden...
            divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
            for( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
                divs[i].style.display = 'none';
            }

            // Now make the one we want to be visible visible...
            document.getElementById(div_id).style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
    <form>
        <input type='button' value='dpara' onclick='arrange(this.value);' />
        <input type='button' value='dtab' onclick='arrange(this.value);' />
        <input type='button' value='ddl' onclick='arrange(this.value);' />
    </form>
    <div id='dpara'>
        123
    </div>

    <div id='dtab'>
        456
    </div>

    <div id='ddl'>
        789
    </div>
```

In addition to this **var visibleDiv** is mean to store the id of the div I'm passing through - but on alert it returns **[object HTTPInputElement]**. Is there a few steps I've missed? Here is mu new code below:

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
var visibleDiv;

function arrange(div) {
    // Cache the passed in 'div' as the currently visible one
    visibleDiv = div;

    alert(visibleDiv);

    // First make all the divs hidden...
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        i,
        len;

    for (i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
        divs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Now make the one we want to be visible visible...
    visibleDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
    </script>
    <form>
        <input type='button' value='dpara' onclick='arrange(this);' />
        <input type='button' value='dtab' onclick='arrange(this);' />
        <input type='button' value='ddl' onclick='arrange(this);' />
    </form>
    <div id='dpara'>123
    </div>

    <div id='dtab' style='display: none'>456
    </div>

    <div id='ddl' style='display: none'>789
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, that's my mistake! You should pass in `arrange("divId");` and then change `visibleDiv = div` to `visibleDiv = document.getElementById(divId);`. You also need to change the name of the input parameter to `arrange` function to be called `divId`.

Comment: @mithunsatheesh: because jQuery's unnecessary for his use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this updated version:

```
var visibleDiv;

function arrange(div) {
    // Cache the passed in 'div' as the currently visible one
    visibleDiv = document.getElementById(div.value);

    // First make all the divs hidden...
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        i,
        len;

    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        divs[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Now make the one we want to be visible visible...
    visibleDiv.style.display = 'block';
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/fXmEu/).

The problems were that you were passing the DOM node into the function, while you needed the `value` from that node. To get around this you could have used: `onclick="arrange(this.value);"` or, as I've chosen to do, pass the DOM node into the function, and then find the value within the function.

Secondly you were assuming that the JavaScript would find the right `div` element without invoking the `document.getElementById()` method, which I've corrected, assigning the the DOM node returned by `document.getElementById(div.value)` to the variable `visibleDiv`. I've also removed the `alert()`. But that wasn't a problem, just to make it look a little better.

Comment: If I alert visibleDiv I don't seem to get the id (or name) of the current div on view? How can I retrieve that id? Your example works perfect but when I try alerting visibleDiv all I get is `[object HTMLDivElement]`!

Comment: Yeah, because the `visibleDiv` is a DOM node. That's what you're supposed to get. If you want to see the id: `alert(visbleDiv.id)`, if you want the `name` (not that a `div` should *have* a `name` attribute) then use: `alert(visibleDiv.name)`.

Answer (score 3):

In your second attempt you are no longer passing in `this.value`. You are just passing in `this`, which is a reference to the `input` element (an `HTMLInputElement`, not `HTTPInputElement` by the way).

However, changing it back to `this.value` still won't work, because of this line:

```
 visibleDiv.style.display = 'block';
```

I would suggest changing the argument back to `this.value` and changing the above line to:

```
 document.getElementById(visibleDiv).style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 2):

In your second example, the onclick handler takes 'this', not 'this.value'. That's why you're getting an HTTPInputElement when you alert on its value.

Answer (score 2):

In your second example try changing

```
onclick='arrange(this)';
```

To this

```
onclick='arrange(this.value)';
```

Answer (score 2):

'this' in the context of your new code, is a reference to the HTML input element that has been clicked on, not a reference to the actual div, which is what I assume you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example works for me.  I used chrome.  Maybe I'm not understanding the problem.  When I ran your first example I saw all three divs, and then clicking any of the buttons shows only the expected div.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to handle this is to make sure the style is on the div elements, and pass "this" not "this.value" to the function. Then you could use this javascript.

```
function clicked(elm) {
    var tabs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;++i) {
        if(tabs[i].style.display == "block") {
            tabs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(elm.value).style.display = "block";
}
```

Your divs should look like:

```
<div id="dpara" style="display:block">
    First Content
</div>

<div id="dtab" style="display:none">
    Second Content
</div>

<div id="ddl" style="display:none">
    Third Content
</div>
```

And your buttons:

```
<input type="button" onclick="clicked(this)" value="dpara" />
<input type="button" onclick="clicked(this)" value="dtab" />
<input type="button" onclick="clicked(this)" value="ddl" />
```